# first: expects a non-empty list

Tags: scheme, racket

I keep getting the error `first: expects a non-empty list` given: `(make-subject (make-person 22 'm 'MW17K) (list 220 301 189 272 311))` when starting my program and just can't find out why.

```
;;equals 25 but my code keeps erroring. please help
(person-age (subject-person (first sub)))     

(define-struct person (age sex code))

(define-struct subject (person times))

(define VP01 (make-subject (make-person 22 'm 'MW17K) (list 220 301 189 272 311)))
(define VP02 (make-subject (make-person 25 'f 'MP25G) (list 234 197 253 257 206)))
(define VP03 (make-subject (make-person 23 'f 'CT03R) (list 197 202 214 222 233)))
(define VP04 (make-subject (make-person 20 'm 'MM09R) (list 273 314 257 264 217)))
(define VP05 (make-subject (make-person 19 'm 'KR22I) (list 198 197 228 253 199)))
(define VP06 (make-subject (make-person 26 'm 'FR01B) (list 212 204 289 294 223)))
(define VP07 (make-subject (make-person 28 'f 'RA15R) (list 258 323 189 247 303)))
(define VP08 (make-subject (make-person 22 'm 'RP18R) (list 221 307 182 271 316)))
(define VP09 (make-subject (make-person 24 'f 'GH31W) (list 230 295 304 264 237)))
(define VP10 (make-subject (make-person 19 'f 'OM29Q) (list 299 194 242 303 243)))

(define subjects (list VP01 VP02 VP03 VP04 VP05 VP06 VP07 VP08 VP09 VP10))

(define (idk sub)
  (cond
    [(empty? sub) empty]        
    [(< (person-age (subject-person (first sub)))
        (person-age (subject-person (first (rest sub)))))
      (idk (first sub))]
    [else (idk (first (rest sub)))]))

(idk subjects)
```

Comment: You'll need to ensure that you always have two people before entering into your second or third conditional expressions. The error is telling you that you're trying to pass the empty list to `(first)` - this happens in the case when `sub` only has one member.

Answer (score 1):

You have a type mismatch:

```
(define (idk sub)   
  (cond
    [(empty? sub) empty]        
    [(< (person-age (subject-person (first sub)))   ; here2 -------- NB
        (person-age (subject-person (first (rest sub)))))
      (idk (first sub))]    ; here1 ------------------------ NB
    [else (idk (first (rest sub)))]))  ; here3

(idk subjects)
```

`idk` is called with a list of `subject`s, so `sub` inside its definition is a list of `subject`s. This means that `(first sub)` at *here1* is a `subject`.

But then you call `idk` with it at *here1* (or *here3*), and it then calls `(first sub)` at *here2*. At this point `sub` is a `subject`, not a list. Hence the error,

> `first`: expects a non-empty list 
>   given: `(make-subject (make-person 22 'm 'MW17K) (list 220 301 189 272 311))`

Answer (score 0):

I think use let and car,cdr make code more clear:

```
(let loop ([loop_list subjects])
   (if (>= (length loop_list) 2)
       (if (>= (person-age (subject-person (car loop_list)))
               (person-age (subject-person (cadr loop_list))))
           (person-age (subject-person (car loop_list)))
           (loop (cdr loop_list)))
       empty))
```